# Is there any rule when inserting a phrase in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, usage

> It is, at least, clear that a free media is no guarentee that the world's fastest cultural changes will be reported.

As "at least" in this sentence, When I read something that is in English it's pretty easy to find phrases put in the middle of a sentence. Is there any rule about when to/where to/how to use them? And I'd love to know its role being in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Your particular example is a ***sentence adverb*** phrase (it doesn't specifically modify any particular verb or noun in the containing utterance; it modifies the whole sentence). Sentence adverbs are pretty flexible about exactly where they can be placed. The most obvious positions are *before* or *after* the rest of the text, but they can often be placed *within* the text. Just be aware that in your specific example, if we placed ***at least*** before, say, ***the world's fastest cultural changes***, or ***be reported***, it would no longer be a sentence adverb, so the meaning would change.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the answer. If I put **at least** at the beginning of that sentence, would it be the same as the original sentence in meaning?

Comment: Yes - if the adverbial element comes at the beginning or end of the utterance, it will normally have "whole sentence" scope. But offhand I can't see any other position *within* your specific example utterance where it could be placed to have that scope. It's effectively meaningless to talk about something being "at least clear" (since "being clear" is already an "extreme" position; it can't really go any further). So in *that* position it must have whole sentence scope, since it can't be adverbially modifying "being clear" as some minimally acceptable aspect of the situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for clearing up! but if there is no difference in meaning whether a sentence adverb go in a sentence, is the position of it just a personal preference in writing? what's the effect sentence adverb placed in the middle of a sentence makes? would it be a pause? It seems like that writing style is pretty common in English. However, if it was for my tongue, I would find it disturbing.

Comment: Whether it's placed before, after, or *within* your cited sentence, the "meaning" of ***at least*** here could be just as well conveyed by a preceding sentence along the lines of, say, "I've learned one thing from my research" (or *followed* by "**So,** I've learned one thing..." ). I'm sure your own language has the equivalent. But if "embedded whole sentence adverbs" seem unnatural to you, just don't use them yourself. I take it you do actually *understand* the intended meaning of the "embedded" version as you cited. But nothing says you have to *copy* it yourself, if it seems weird to you.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Thank you for all the helps!